# Get position of last character in a substring

Tags: php, string, substring, echo

```
$big = "new york city";
$small ="or";
$pos = strpos($big, $small);
echo $pos;
```

Returns 5 but I want it to return 6 which is the position of "r". Thanks in advance

Comment: `$pos = $pos + strlen($small) - 1`

Comment: Add the length of the substring minus 1. Should be obvious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$big = "new york city";
$small ="or";
$pos = strpos($big, $small);
$pos = $pos + strlen($small) - 1;

echo $pos;
```

Comment: Thanks. @kombian. I don't know why that solution didnt occur to me